# Creating diagram of neural network

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, diagram

I wanted to create a visual diagram for my neural network. I started with a LeNet style using NN-SVG to diagram my convolutional neural network, but I wasn't sure which numbers to plug in where. The filters for my layers double each layer, whilst filter size stays static at 3*3.

Below is the code for the CNN, it was made for the CIFAR-10 dataset.

```
model = Sequential([
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (32, 32, 3)),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
  layers.Dense(10) 
])
```

[Attempted Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv3zL.png) doesn't look quite right, I've put the depth of each layer as the amount of nodes in that layer, but is this correct or should it be 3 for the amount of channels?